# Change window.location.hash with mouse wheel event

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mouseevent, scrollto

Im using ScrollTo and localscroll to navigate a site im building, but I would like to be able to use scroll from section to section as well, but in an order Im choosing. Im looking at mouse wheel event to achieve this (don´t know if this is the way to go). The setup is nine divs layed out in a square pattern within a div sized 300%x300% of window size, similar to this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Katalo/akr6fbvf/6/) (but it covers the entire window).

I have tried to make thee mouse wheel event change the window.location.hash because (I think) that would make localscroll use its regular effects for navigation between the divs.

This is the code I have tried, and the array is the order of which I would like the divs to appear:

```
    var mysections=[
    "5",
    "2",
    "6",
    "8",
    "4",
    "7",
    "9",
    "1",
    "3"
]

var nextsectionindex=0

function rotatesection(e){
    var evt=window.event || e 
    var delta=evt.detail? evt.detail*(-120) : evt.wheelDelta 
    nextsectionindex=(delta<=-120)? nextsectionindex+1 : nextsectionindex-1 
    nextsectionindex=(nextsectionindex<0)? mysections.length-1 : (nextsectionindex>mysections.length-1)? 0 : nextsectionindex 
    window.location.hash=mysections[nextsectionindex] 
}
```

But I cant get it to work, is there something missing or wrong in the above code? How can I test if the delta is changing (since I dont have any scroll bars)?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Sorry, wasnt specific. Did an edit.

Comment: Ever solved this?